# Generate decimal values and assign them to a dataframe based on constraints

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with values :

```
min max
2   4
4   6
6   8
8   10
10  12
12  14
14  16
16  18
18  20
20  22
22  24
24  26
26  28
28  30
30  32
32  34
34  36
36  38
38  40
40  42
42  44
44  46
46  48
48  50
```

min and max are ranges to generate the decimal values(upto 2 decimal points).

I want to randomly pick a range (min-max) and then generate decimal values in such a way for another df2 such that :

if df2.is_b = 1, then generate a random decimal number(upto 2 decimal places) from the randomly picked range..(from df1) such that values after 1st quartile are picked up.

if df2.is_b = 0, then generate decimal number from same range below first quartile.

for example - if range picked is 2-4, then for a date_1, and a range(randomly picked), generate decimal number after 1st quartile (if is_b = 1) and generate decimal number before 1st quartile (if is_b = 0).

df2 looks like :

```
date_1  is_b
01/09/2019  0
01/09/2019  0
01/09/2019  1
01/09/2019  0
01/09/2019  1
01/09/2019  0
01/09/2019  1
01/09/2019  0
01/09/2019  0
01/09/2019  0
01/09/2019  1
01/09/2019  0
02/09/2019  1
02/09/2019  1
02/09/2019  1
02/09/2019  0
02/09/2019  0
02/09/2019  0
02/09/2019  0
02/09/2019  1
02/09/2019  0
02/09/2019  1
```

Can anyone help with the same.

**EDIT**

the output would be different for each date, however I am showing for 2 dates(as represented in df2)

picked range for 01/09/2019 is (2-4) and picked range for 02/09/2019 is (6-8). then for all values of is_B for 01/09/2019, the range of value would be : (2.50-4.0) and for is_b = 0 the value range would be (2-2.5)

```
    date_1     is_b    value
    01/09/2019  0       2.12
    01/09/2019  0       2.09
    01/09/2019  1       2.58(since is_b = 1)
    01/09/2019  0        .
    01/09/2019  1        . 
    01/09/2019  0
    01/09/2019  1
    01/09/2019  0
    01/09/2019  0
    01/09/2019  0
    01/09/2019  1
    01/09/2019  0
    02/09/2019  1       7.23
    02/09/2019  1       6.80
    02/09/2019  1       6.81
    02/09/2019  0       6.23
    02/09/2019  0       .
    02/09/2019  0       .
    02/09/2019  0
    02/09/2019  1
    02/09/2019  0
    02/09/2019  1
```

Comment: what did you try already? Can you also show the expected output? Thanks!

Comment: “such that values until 3rd quartile are picked up.” I don’t understand what you mean by “3rd quartile” throughout your question, can you rephrase/explain further?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile my apologies, I have edited the question, also have added example in the edit.

Comment: @baccandr I have added expected output as well

Comment: @vp7 I appreciate you trying to improve things, but I was having trouble with your use of the word _quartile_, not the particular quartile :p I should have been clearer lol

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Did you get the question now? Would you be able to help?

Comment: @vp7 I still don’t understand how you calculate the value range, its effect on the value, or the effect of `is_b`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202188/discussion-between-vp7-and-alexander-cecile).

Comment: @AlexanderCécile the value range is randomly sampled from df1 (df1.sample()), we get the min and max from there and then we do the next computation steps

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Did you get a chance to take a look at it.